# Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.AzAuthorizationStoreClass.Initialize fails with System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: azman, fileloadexception

Our ASP.NET web application uses Authorization manager. On a page of this web application, the authorization store which is a local XML file on the server is accessed many times to perform access check. Some clients of ours are getting a `System.IO.FileLoadException` when they access this page. This is intermittent.

Stack trace:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: **The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process.** (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070020)    at
>   Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.AzAuthorizationStoreClass.Initialize(Int32
>   lFlags, String bstrPolicyURL, Object varReserved)

The process monitor shows a **SHARING VIOLATION**. I have searched for a solution, but could not find one. The client is on Windows Server 2003 SP2. So this hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919754 does not seem to apply because it is part of Windows Server 2003 SP2.

The code to access the authorization store is like this:

```
private IAzApplication2 AzmanApplication
{
    get
    {
        AzAuthorizationStoreClass store = new AzAuthorizationStoreClass();
        store.Initialize(0, _connectionString, null);
        return store.OpenApplication2(_applicationName, null);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

this means that file (probably the XML file you have for AzMan) is open in another application.
make sure azman.mmc is not running having this store open for edit/review etc.